# Timeout error when using SMTPLIB in python

Tags: python-3.x, smtplib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wanx5.png)

Doing a python course via udemy and was working on SMTPLIB. I created an app password after activating 2FA on my gmail account as advised by my course instructor.

Why am i experiencing this error and how can i fix it. The email is not being sent.

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: whats missing in my question?

Comment: You have used an image instead of actual code, not stated what you have tried to fix it, what version of python and SMTPLIB you are using..... its all in the page i linked.